# Why does $\ln(I+A)$ converge when $\|A\|<1$?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. Often times you can take the logarithm
$$\ln(I_n+A)=A-A^2/2+A^3/3-\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}A^n/n$$

when the matrix norm $\|A\|<1$.

Is there a reference/proof of why this series actually converges entrywise to matrix under this condition?

Comment: Do you know why $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-+\cdots$ for $|x|<1$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I'm not familiar with that, but does it follow by applying the root test to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$?

Comment: @hmIII:  or maybe the ratio test? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\|A\|<1$ then the series 
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k}\|A\|^k$$
is convergent (and its sum is $-\log(1-\|A\|)$ ) so by The Cauchy criterion given $\epsilon>0$ there's $N$ such that $p>m\geq N$ we have
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^p\frac{1}{k}\|A\|^k<\epsilon$$
and by the triangle inequality we have
$$\left\|\sum_{k=m+1}^p\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}A^k\right\|\leq \sum_{k=m+1}^p\frac{1}{k}\|A\|^k<\epsilon$$
so the series 
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}A^k$$
is also convergent.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

If a power series for a function $\sum c_n x^n$ has a radius of convergence $R$, then if there exists a matrix norm such that $\|A\|<R$ then the series with $f(A)$ also converges.  The proof and a more complete discussion is in Horn and Johnson, Matrix Analysis Section 5.6.